# How to check for Auth user in Swift while allowing JWT Refresh?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, jwt

I want to be able to have a single Bool method that checks if a user is logged in, and if so returns the token to be used in the API header.

```
func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    if let authToken = AuthManager.loadAuthToken() {
        if authToken.expiration.isGreaterThanDate(Date()) {
            return true
        } else {
            let authAPI = AuthenticationAPI()

            authAPI.refreshToken(token: authToken.token) { (results) in
                switch results {
                case .success(let response):
                    [HAVE PARENT METHOD RETURN TRUE]
                case .failure:
                    removeAuthToken()
                    [HAVE PARENT METHOD RETURN FALSE]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

I have this mostly working, however, I am running into a wall trying to figure out how to allow the app to attempt the refresh token call when there is a token present, but it is expired.

Semaphores seem like the way to go, but seem to quickly complicate the code. Is this the way it should be done or is there a better approach that is usually done for this?

Comment: I'd go for lazy evaluation - always assume it's valid. Act upon failure and don't hold the state in your code when you don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take a different approach.

In an `AuthManager` type of class, I store the token in an optional var.  If the token is present, then I assume it is valid to be used in an API call.  In the `didSet` for the token, there is a `Notification.Name.authStatusDidChange` notification which is sent so the app can respond accordingly.

If the API call returns a `401` then I notify the `AuthManager` to clear the token (which triggers the notification, and in my case shows the login flow).
However, you could have additional logic which rather than clearing the token, the `Authmanager` first tries to refresh it.  If the refresh succeeds, then a different notification is sent to retry the API request.  Otherwise it clears the token and triggers a sign in.

**While I was Typing** - Like Michal said, with a little more detail.

Comment: Then the user would be responsible for trying again (because the call would have failed)?

Comment: In my case, yes.  I want to force a re-authentication.  However, in your case, you could trigger an async token refresh, and if that failed then show the re-authentication workflow.  If the refresh was successful, retry the previous API request.  Alamofire has methodology for this.

Comment: This exactly what I meant, but I was on my phone rather than computer. Cheers!

Comment: I know this is super late but I have a question, if the API calls returns a 401 and I want to refresh the token and it succeeds, how do I retry the last URL called which got the 401 error? Do I store a variable that holds the last URL the application requested?